# Obtener el índice de un elemento en un array en php

Tags: php

Necesito saber como obtener la posición de un elemento dentro de un arreglo de php
Mi array tiene esta estructra:

```
$array = ["precio1" => 2.33]
```

He intentando todo, incluso array_search y sólo me da de resultado el primer elemento del array

Comment: Pero no sé como @element

Comment: Si entendi bien vos querias saber en que posicion esta "precio1" lo que te tendria que devolver posicion 0, no?

Comment: Exactly. Si me devolvería, porque es el primer elemento, lo que pasa es que cuando pruebo con todos los otros, sólo me da el resultado del primero

Comment: Cual es el orden que siguen tus variables? Digo, si ese es el único valor que va a tener el array ya sabes que es cero sin hacer nada, pero, se agregan mas variables? Es dinámico? No sabia que se podía hacer como te pasan en la respuesta por lo que me puse a pushear dentro de otro array la posicion y el valor https://paiza.io/projects/NRxF08oI_TxJspfUF69Oiw calculo que lo que pusieron como respuesta te sirve, siempre y cuando sepas la clave que estas buscando y no tengas que realizar un for por ejemplo en base al total de elementos para ir a buscar en otros segun la posicion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a la respuesta de @Fosco en SO en inglés: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365766/php-get-numeric-index-of-associative-array

Lo puedes obtener de este modo

```
$array = ["precio" => 1, "precio1" => 2.33];

echo array_search("precio1",array_keys($array));
```

Lo cual me devuelve 1, por que `precio1` esta en la posición 1 del índice del array

Como observas

- Hacemos un echo de la función `array_search`
- Por dentro a la función le pasamos la `key` que deseamos encontrar
- Hacemos uso de la función `array_keys()` como segundo argumento y le pasamos el nombre del array asociativo